# How I can get average number of array`s element, when array doesn`t have only integer type data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have array with 3 data types: `NSString(Employe's name)` `NSString(Employee's last name)` and `int(salary)`. This elements created by constructor:

```
 -(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)employeesName andLastName:(NSString *) employeesLastName andSalary:(int)employeesSalary;
```

I need to count average salary using another method, how I can do it?

definition of array:

```
 @property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Employee *> *employees;
```

method which add object to array:

```
-(void) addEmployeeWithName:(NSString *)employeesName andLastName:(NSString *)employeesLastName andSalary:(int)employeesSalary
{

    Employee *myEmp =[[Employee alloc] initWithFirstName:employeesName lastName:employeesLastName salary:employeesSalary];
    [self.employees addObject:myEmp];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the array and how things are being added to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the KVC method `valueForKeyPath:` with attribute `@avg` on the array

```
NSNumber *average = [self.employees valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.salary"];
NSLog(@"%ld", average.integerValue);
```

Comment: While this may be a good answer (few lines of code, use of KVC), the author seems to be missing algorithm basics knowledge, and while/for loops and if tests may be a better solution for him/her, and I'd recommend him/her to keep this answer in mind, but not use it.